# Multi level dropdown in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I'd like to know if there is a way to configure a dropdown to show multiple levels (or a dropdown of an item in the main control) much like those seen often in websites. I know those are JavaScript based which is of no use for me. I have been searching on-line and I don't think is possible out-of-the-box. Most examples I found were a mix of Tree controls and something else. Is that the only way? Any ideas on that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your targeted framework?  ASP.NET/web?  WinForms/Desktop?  WCF?  Silverlight?

Comment: I don't think it is available. Only way(not sure possible) using Javascript - If your platform is ASP.Net

Comment: You could maybe achieve this with a context menu.

Comment: You never mentioned what type of user interface you are working in.  Is it WPF, Silverlight, WinForm, ASP.NET, something else?  The platform your UI is in greatly changes the answer.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of framework. It is a desktop application and I am working with WinForms. I think I can embed some WPF if needed too. Actually I know WPF has a very flexible Menu which accepts some other controls in it. So, that maybe it.

Comment: Yes you can do this with WPF.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question so it includes all essential information instead of having it somewhere in the comments.